# Android SeekBar thumb gets clipped/cut off

Tags: android, android-seekbar

When using a custom thumb drawable with a `SeekBar` view, the thumb drawable is clipped at the left and right edges of the view.

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by setting [`paddingLeft`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:paddingLeft) and `paddingRight` on your `SeekBar` to half the thumb width (remember to use density-independent units). You can also control the space allowed at the edges for a seek bar's thumb by calling [`setThumbOffset`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#setThumbOffset(int)).

Comment: What's the deault size of default thumb?

Comment: @Hurda The mdpi (holo) size is 32x32 and the mdpi (pre-holo) is 32x29

Comment: Note, if you are working with VerticalSeekBars, you STILL use paddingRight & paddingLeft

Comment: This happened to me even without a custom thumb drawable, just using different themes based on platform version. Setting `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` to `16dp` seemed to be the way to be sure it works in all versions with all standard themes.

Comment: This is definitely the fix to use, works on 2.3.3 and 4.x for me.

Comment: Using both the `ThumbOffset` and the `padding` causes the thumb to NOT reach the end of the seekbar on 4.4.2. A little bit of the track is visible to the right even after moving the thumb to the end. If i use only padding, it looks fine. But on 3.0, i have to use `ThumbOffset` and `padding` to avoid the thumb getting clipped. Is it possible to manage this situation so that it looks good on all versions?

Comment: @Roman Nurik  paddingLeft and paddingRight is not doing anything for my seekbar

Comment: Adding `android:thumbOffset="-0dp"` did it for me

Comment: I used a rather large thumb image (but reasonable size) and padding alone wouldn't fix it. I ended up using `android:paddingLeft="20dp" android:paddingRight="20dp" android:thumbOffset="16dp"`

Comment: Important to note the difference between the two solutions in this answer: adding a padding causes the line to occupy less of the seek bar's area and that might be not what you want. The offset on the other hand limits the movement of the thumb drawable stopping it before the edge of the line (when the edge of the thumb is on the edge and not the middle of it). That might also be not what you want.

Answer (score 31):

I ran into this issue myself, and I believe the **`"correct"`** decision would be to modify `android:thumbOffset` as the default style for a **SeekBar** sets it to 8px.

Comment: +1! My designer will appreciate this approach, so now our slider's track can align on the left and right with everything else as expected. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: android:thumbOffset  has no effect on 2.3.3. I had to use padding.

Comment: `android:thumOffset` has no effect on 2.3.3 but you can use the `setThumbOffset` method.

Comment: This is actually the right and useful answer, BIG thanks!

Answer (score 9):

For default SeekBar I used these settings and it works fine:

```
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"

android:thumbOffset="8dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification.

On some places I have seen

```
 android:thumbOffset="8dp"
```

and some

```
android:thumbOffset="8px"
```

so I looked at the source code. this is the original style

```
<style name="Widget.SeekBar">
        <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@android:drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
        <item name="android:thumb">@android:drawable/seek_thumb</item>
        <item name="android:thumbOffset">8dip</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    </style>
```

from

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the bottom of my default seekbar thumb clipped. None of the fixes here worked. I ended up using

```
     android:clipToPadding="false"
```

on the parent view. This solved issue.

Comment: I also had to add clipChildren="false" on the parent to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_loan_period"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_15"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar"
        android:thumb="@drawable/ic_slider"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_0"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp_0"
        android:thumbOffset="-0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/label_loan_period" />
```

This gets the job done

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me but I just changed the color of the thumb different then the background color of the parent layout and it worked for me.