# Custom seekbar getting its edges cut

Tags: android, seekbar, custom-view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android SeekBar thumb gets clipped/cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912609/android-seekbar-thumb-gets-clipped-cut-off)

I was doing a custom seekbar, following this tutorial: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

But when I put the seek thumb either at the begining or at the end of the bar, its edge gets cut, like this:
http://s2.postimage.org/d9dqrrms/myseekbar.png

I've done exactly what the tutorial says (just changed the gradient color).
What's wrong?

Comment: Try this : http://www.anddev.org/seekbar_progressbar_customizing-t6083.html Maybe helpful for you.

Comment: Wow, and I thought I had searched enough. Yes, seems duplicated, sorry. Now everything works fine with these SeekBar properties: android:thumbOffset="9px" android:paddingRight="9px" android:paddingLeft="9px". My thumb is 18px width, so I put 9px offset and padding. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried setting the thumb offset for the thumb drawable?

```
android:thumbOffset="-1px"
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. The only problem is that now the blue background exceeds the thumb, like this http://s2.postimage.org/elxttllw/myseekbar2.png Is there something to do with that? Still, I'm happy its edges aren't cut anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the left and right padding for the seekbar instead of the thumb offset that should do what you want it to do.

```
android:paddingLeft="1px" 
android:paddingRight="1px"
```

Comment: Why do you use `px` here instead of `dp`?

Comment: Been so long I can't remember if there was a reason it could have been I was still teaching myself how to program in Android.