# Android: how to remove seekbar thumb space

Tags: android, seekbar

I would like to remove the space arround the thumb in my Seekbar:

(it's the area between red round and the side of blue rectangle, drawn for this example)

[image]

I followed this link but no change: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925892/3409503

This is the style of the Seekbar:

```
<style name="MediaSeekBar" parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/media_seek_bar</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/media_seek_bar_thumb</item>
        <item name="android:thumbOffset">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:progress">0</item>
    </style>
```

My drawable **media_seek_bar_thumb**:

All these drawables are PNG.

Comment: post code of `media_seek_bar_thumb`

Comment: try `<item name="android:thumbOffset">8dip</item>`  or any other value

Comment: I've updated my original post

Comment: is thumb offset not working?

Comment: not at all Redman

Comment: then remove `media_seek_bar_thumb`, it's big png `image`. you should use default `thumb`

Comment: Try setting android:background="@null"

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and it turned out that there was some transparent padding baked into my .png files.  The fix was to set

`android:splitTrack="false"`

on the Seekbar in the Activity's layout xml.  This will force the two track segments to connect behind your thumb drawable.